# Extension module (*.so) is not produced after using f2py

Tags: python, f2py

I use Win7, and installed Anaconda for python and gfortran (MINGW) for fortran.

After using f2py, I cannot find a extension module file.
I tried the example in the following links:

[Three ways to wrap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/f2py/getting-started.html)

[F2PY - Calling Fortran routines from Python](https://www.numfys.net/howto/F2PY/)

If I type as follows in the Anaconda prompt,

```
<base> C:\Codes\F2PY> f2py -c --fcompiler=gfortran -m fib1 fib1.f
```

Then, `fib1.cp36-win_amd64.pyd` file and `fib1` folder is generated.
`.libs` folder is located under the `fib` folder, and there exists `libfib1.5W62YGKMVL6PD3QLPPSXTQ2OGA5LRIRQ.gfortran-win_amd64` file in the `.libs` folder.

However, the expected extension module (`fib1.so`) is not generated.

Is there anything I missed?

I already checked gfortran and python are working well seprately.

```
C:\Codes\F2PY>f2py -c --fcompiler=gfortran -m fib1 fib1.f   
C:\Codes\F2PY>call "D:\Anaconda\Scripts\\..\python.exe" "D:\Anaconda\Scripts\\f2py.py" -c --fcompiler=gfortran -m fib1 fib1.f
Unknown vendor: "gfortran"
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, 
build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, 
build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "fib1" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:>C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\src.win-amd64-3.6\fib1module.c
creating C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\src.win-amd64-3.6
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'fib1.f' (format:fix,strict)
Post-processing...
        Block: fib1
                    Block: fib
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
       Building module "fib1"...
            Constructing wrapper function "fib"...
              fib(a,[n])
    Wrote C/API module "fib1" to file "C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\src.win-amd64-3.6\fib1module.c"
  adding 'C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\src.win-amd64-3.6\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\src.win-amd64-3.6' to include_dirs.
copying D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\src.win-amd64-3.6
copying D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\src.win-amd64-3.6
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
customize MSVCCompiler
customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'fib1' extension
compiling C sources
creating C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\Release\Users
creating C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\Release\Users\6829396
creating C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\Release\Users\6829396\AppData
creating C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\Release\Users\6829396\AppData\Local
creating C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\Release\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp
creating C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_\Release\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpkzx_h7w_
```

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo
/INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0 /LIBPATH:c:\mingw\lib /LIBPATH:D:\Anaconda\libs /LIBPATH:D:\Anaconda\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:D:\Anaconda\libs /LIBPATH:D:\Anaconda\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\lib\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\lib\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_fib1
C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo3wc2rbs\Release\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo3wc2rbs\src.win-amd64-3.6\fib1module.obj C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo3wc2rbs\Release\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo3wc2rbs\src.win-amd64-3.6\fortranobject.obj C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo3wc2rbs\Release\libfib1.5W62YGKMVL6PD3QLPPSXTQ2OGA5LRIRQ.gfortran-win_amd64.lib /OUT:.\fib1.cp36-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo3wc2rbs\Release\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo3wc2rbs\src.win-amd64-3.6\fib1.cp36-win_amd64.lib
    copying C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo3wc2rbs\Release\.libs\libfib1.5W62YGKMVL6PD3QLPPSXTQ2OGA5LRIRQ.gfortran-win_amd64.dll -> .\fib1\.libs
Removing build directory C:\Users\6829396\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpo3wc2rbs`

Answer (score 0):

I also use Win 7 + Anaconda + gfortran (MINGW) and had the same problem trying to wrap a `subroutine distan(x,nx,nd,d)` contained in a `sdistan.f90` file.

The command `python -m numpy.f2py -c -m sdistan sdistan.f90` generated a `sdistan.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` file instead of a `*.so` module.

After analyzing the `sdistan.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` file with [depends.exe](https://www.dependencywalker.com), I discovered that there were two unresolved external dependencies:

(1) the `libsdistan.LD66OEXBPEJ74HMF6SZDLFFCVSPSTQVW.gfortran-win_amd64.dll` DLL file that *f2py* places in the `sdistan/.libs` folder.

(2) and `python3.dll`

I copied these two files (the second from `C:/Anaconda3/python3.dll`) into my working directory and the problem was solved.

Now I can `import sdistan` and I can use my function as `output=sdistan.distan` (input arguments).

I hope this can help those who find the same problem. It would be nice if somebody could explain and correct this (strange/miss) behavior of *f2py*.

Thanks to everybody contributing to Stack Overflow!!